# Selecting multiple columns from previous row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

Suppose I have a table like this:

| id | date | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-01-14 | foo | one |
| 1 | 2017-01-17 | bar | two |
| 2 | 2017-01-18 | john | five |
| 3 | 2017-01-19 | doe | ten |

(where `date` need not necessarily be ordered)

I want to be able to select some values of the *previous* row (based on `date`). Such a functionality can be achieved by the following query:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (SELECT 
     name 
   FROM 
     example e2 
   WHERE 
     e2.dt < e1.dt 
   ORDER BY dt DESC 
   LIMIT 1
   ) as prev_name 
FROM example e1
```

with resulting table:

| id | dt | name | value | prev_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-01-14 | foo | one | (null) |
| 1 | 2017-01-17 | bar | two | foo |
| 2 | 2017-01-18 | john | five | bar |
| 3 | 2017-01-19 | doe | ten | john |

Now, this works just fine. However, it would be preferable if I could easily select *multiple* columns from the previous row, resulting in a result like:

| id | dt | name | value | prev_name | prev_value | prev_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-01-14 | foo | one | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2017-01-17 | bar | two | foo | one | 2017-01-14 |
| 2 | 2017-01-18 | john | five | bar | two | 2017-01-17 |
| 3 | 2017-01-19 | doe | ten | john | five | 2017-01-18 |

This can of course be accomplished by simply copying the subquery `(SELECT [..] FROM example e2 ...)` into the query multiple times, but I guess this is not the preferable way to go. I have found several question on SO addressing *either* the "how to select records from a previous row" *or* the "how to select multiple columns using subqueries" problem, but not both. The latter problem is then mostly solved by using a `JOIN` statement, but I think this is not combinable with the "previous row" case. So my question is: what would be a better way to produce the last result, rather then copying a subquery for every column we need?

**EDIT.** As an extra constraint, that I did not include in the original question, "previous" could actually be something different from the previous row, but rather "the previous row that satisfies a condition". So suppose my table contains an extra `boolean` column `b`

| id | dt | name | value | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-01-14 | foo | one | 1 |
| 1 | 2017-01-17 | bar | two | 0 |
| 2 | 2017-01-18 | john | five | 1 |
| 3 | 2017-01-19 | doe | ten | 0 |

I would want the "previous row" to be the previous row with `b = 1`, so the desired result would be:

| id | dt | name | value | b | prev_name | prev_value | prev_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-01-14 | foo | one | 1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2017-01-17 | bar | two | 0 | foo | one | 2017-01-14 |
| 2 | 2017-01-18 | john | five | 1 | foo | one | 2017-01-14 |
| 3 | 2017-01-19 | doe | ten | 0 | john | five | 2017-01-18 |

I think this can still be accomplished by James Scott's answer, by simply only updating the variables when `b = 1`, using an `IF`-statement, but maybe there is another solution possible in this case.

**EDIT.** [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37a68e/18)

Comment: Just in case you've already read my answer, I made a mistake, have now corrected this

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please comment your problem statement.

Comment: I want to select all rows such that the previous row has value `x`, name `y` etc. This can be done by embedding the query I am looking for in `SELECT * FROM ([query]) as temp WHERE prev_name = [..] AND prev_value = [..]`. Furthermore, I have not been entirely complete in my original question, I have added some extra information in an Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will return the id of the 'previous' row.

```
 SELECT x.*
      , MAX(y.id) prev_id
   FROM example x
   LEFT
   JOIN example y
     ON y.id < x.id 
    AND y.b = 1
  GROUP
     BY x.id;
```

I'll leave the business of returning the rest of the data associated with this row as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good use case for session variables if you only want the previous row, you can use `ORDER BY` to get different results.

```
SET @VDt := NULL, @VName := NULL, @VValue := NULL;

SELECT  id, @VName prev_name, @VValue prev_value, @VDt prev_dt, @VDt := dt dt, @VName := `name` `name`, @VValue := `value` `value` FROM example;
```

Messed this up when I first posted, note that the variables must be set after they are returned from the previous row. To reorder the columns (if desired) you can wrap this query in another that then reorders the result columns.

Let me know if you need anything else,

Regards,

James

Comment: I added some extra information on my problem, as also mentioned in the comments below my question. As mentioned, I think your query can be altered to work in my case, but maybe there is also another solution that works better